# quotient module with dimensional 1

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory

If $V=\bigoplus V_{i}$ is an n-dimensional $R$-module and $W$ is a hyperplane "submodule of V" whose coordinates sum equal to zero (thus it is of $\ n-1$ dimension). If the quotient space $V/W$ is also an $R$-module; thus it's of $\ 1$-dimension. I want to show that bais of the quotient module is $v_{i}+W$ no matter what $v_{i}\in V_{i}$ is. I mean even $v_{i}+w=v_{j}+W.$ Can you please provide me with a hint?

Comment: $v_i+W=v_j+W\iff v_i-v_j\in W$

Comment: Does it mean that the only coset of the quotient we have is the $W$?

Comment: What is $R$?  You mean $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No it is a ring.